# Monerod synchronization very slow on SSD with good network bandwidth

Tags: monerod, synchronization, blockchain-import

I'm trying to sync local node.
I downloaded the monero blockchain.raw file and imported it using `monero-blockchain-import`. Importing the blockchain took about 5 hours. But for some reasons it imported about 45000 less blocks. Also, I want to notice that the import of the blockchain was faster at the beginning than at the end, many times. last blocks for some reason were imported very slowly. So, after start `monerod` it starts synchronization, but so slow.
Log:

```
2021-03-15 18:24:54.773 I Synced 2271245/2317737 (97%, 46492 left)
2021-03-15 18:25:00.751 I Synced 2271265/2317737 (97%, 46472 left)
2021-03-15 18:25:10.519 I Synced 2271285/2317737 (97%, 46452 left)
2021-03-15 18:25:18.699 I Synced 2271305/2317737 (97%, 46432 left)
2021-03-15 18:25:24.959 I Synced 2271325/2317737 (97%, 46412 left)
2021-03-15 18:25:29.874 I Synced 2271345/2317737 (97%, 46392 left)
2021-03-15 18:25:36.457 I Synced 2271365/2317737 (97%, 46372 left)
2021-03-15 18:25:46.670 I Synced 2271385/2317737 (98%, 46352 left)
2021-03-15 18:25:52.261 I Synced 2271405/2317737 (98%, 46332 left)
2021-03-15 18:25:58.843 I Synced 2271425/2317737 (98%, 46312 left)
2021-03-15 18:26:04.024 I Synced 2271445/2317737 (98%, 46292 left)
2021-03-15 18:26:09.079 I Synced 2271465/2317737 (98%, 46272 left)
2021-03-15 18:26:15.328 I Synced 2271485/2317737 (98%, 46252 left)
2021-03-15 18:26:21.505 I Synced 2271505/2317737 (98%, 46232 left)
2021-03-15 18:26:29.700 I Synced 2271525/2317738 (98%, 46213 left)
2021-03-15 18:26:39.270 I Synced 2271545/2317738 (98%, 46193 left)
2021-03-15 18:26:46.020 I Synced 2271565/2317738 (98%, 46173 left)
2021-03-15 18:26:53.512 I Synced 2271585/2317738 (98%, 46153 left)
2021-03-15 18:26:59.899 I Synced 2271605/2317738 (98%, 46133 left)
2021-03-15 18:27:08.317 I Synced 2271625/2317740 (98%, 46115 left, 0% of total synced, estimated 4.4 hours left)
2021-03-15 18:27:14.147 I Synced 2271645/2317740 (98%, 46095 left)
2021-03-15 18:27:21.792 I Synced 2271665/2317740 (98%, 46075 left)
2021-03-15 18:27:27.100 I Synced 2271685/2317740 (98%, 46055 left)
2021-03-15 18:27:34.202 I Synced 2271705/2317740 (98%, 46035 left)
2021-03-15 18:27:40.949 I Synced 2271725/2317740 (98%, 46015 left)
2021-03-15 18:27:46.942 I Synced 2271745/2317740 (98%, 45995 left)
2021-03-15 18:27:52.069 I Synced 2271765/2317740 (98%, 45975 left)
2021-03-15 18:27:58.250 I Synced 2271785/2317740 (98%, 45955 left)
2021-03-15 18:28:04.739 I Synced 2271805/2317740 (98%, 45935 left)
2021-03-15 18:28:13.010 I Synced 2271825/2317740 (98%, 45915 left)
2021-03-15 18:28:17.370 I Synced 2271845/2317740 (98%, 45895 left)
2021-03-15 18:28:25.321 I Synced 2271865/2317740 (98%, 45875 left)
2021-03-15 18:28:31.895 I Synced 2271885/2317740 (98%, 45855 left)
2021-03-15 18:28:38.626 I Synced 2271905/2317740 (98%, 45835 left)
2021-03-15 18:28:45.254 I Synced 2271925/2317740 (98%, 45815 left)
2021-03-15 18:28:49.819 I Synced 2271945/2317740 (98%, 45795 left)
2021-03-15 18:28:53.173 I Synced 2271965/2317740 (98%, 45775 left)
2021-03-15 18:28:58.523 I Synced 2271985/2317740 (98%, 45755 left)
2021-03-15 18:29:05.287 I Synced 2272005/2317740 (98%, 45735 left)
2021-03-15 18:29:11.384 I Synced 2272025/2317740 (98%, 45715 left, 1% of total synced, estimated 4.1 hours left)
2021-03-15 18:29:16.773 I Synced 2272045/2317740 (98%, 45695 left)
2021-03-15 18:29:25.851 I Synced 2272065/2317740 (98%, 45675 left)
2021-03-15 18:29:30.902 I Synced 2272085/2317740 (98%, 45655 left)
2021-03-15 18:29:36.412 I Synced 2272105/2317740 (98%, 45635 left)
2021-03-15 18:29:46.063 I Synced 2272125/2317740 (98%, 45615 left)
2021-03-15 18:29:54.860 I Synced 2272145/2317740 (98%, 45595 left)
2021-03-15 18:29:59.007 I Synced 2272165/2317740 (98%, 45575 left)
2021-03-15 18:30:05.438 I Synced 2272185/2317740 (98%, 45555 left)
2021-03-15 18:30:11.859 I Synced 2272205/2317740 (98%, 45535 left)
2021-03-15 18:30:18.556 I Synced 2272225/2317740 (98%, 45515 left)
2021-03-15 18:30:26.225 I Synced 2272245/2317740 (98%, 45495 left)
2021-03-15 18:30:34.812 I Synced 2272265/2317740 (98%, 45475 left)
2021-03-15 18:30:44.176 I Synced 2272285/2317740 (98%, 45455 left)
2021-03-15 18:30:55.428 I Synced 2272305/2317740 (98%, 45435 left)
2021-03-15 18:31:04.315 I Synced 2272325/2317740 (98%, 45415 left)
2021-03-15 18:31:18.543 I Synced 2272345/2317740 (98%, 45395 left, 2% of total synced, estimated 4.4 hours left)
2021-03-15 18:31:25.909 I Synced 2272365/2317740 (98%, 45375 left)
2021-03-15 18:31:38.463 I Synced 2272385/2317740 (98%, 45355 left)
2021-03-15 18:31:45.467 I Synced 2272405/2317740 (98%, 45335 left)
2021-03-15 18:31:51.793 I Synced 2272425/2317740 (98%, 45315 left)
2021-03-15 18:32:01.339 I Synced 2272445/2317740 (98%, 45295 left)
2021-03-15 18:32:08.232 I Synced 2272465/2317740 (98%, 45275 left)
2021-03-15 18:32:17.883 I Synced 2272485/2317740 (98%, 45255 left)
2021-03-15 18:32:26.537 I Synced 2272505/2317740 (98%, 45235 left)
2021-03-15 18:32:32.654 I Synced 2272525/2317740 (98%, 45215 left)
2021-03-15 18:32:39.348 I Synced 2272545/2317740 (98%, 45195 left)
2021-03-15 18:32:46.064 I Synced 2272565/2317740 (98%, 45175 left)
2021-03-15 18:32:53.454 I Synced 2272585/2317740 (98%, 45155 left)
2021-03-15 18:33:01.511 I Synced 2272605/2317740 (98%, 45135 left)
2021-03-15 18:33:11.448 I Synced 2272625/2317740 (98%, 45115 left)
2021-03-15 18:33:17.465 I Synced 2272645/2317741 (98%, 45096 left)
2021-03-15 18:33:24.523 I Synced 2272665/2317741 (98%, 45076 left, 3% of total synced, estimated 4.5 hours left)
2021-03-15 18:33:33.836 I Synced 2272685/2317741 (98%, 45056 left)
2021-03-15 18:33:39.555 I Synced 2272705/2317741 (98%, 45036 left)
2021-03-15 18:33:46.267 I Synced 2272725/2317741 (98%, 45016 left)
2021-03-15 18:33:51.435 I Synced 2272745/2317741 (98%, 44996 left)
2021-03-15 18:33:56.630 I Synced 2272765/2317741 (98%, 44976 left)
2021-03-15 18:34:02.747 I Synced 2272785/2317741 (98%, 44956 left)
2021-03-15 18:34:07.603 I Synced 2272805/2317741 (98%, 44936 left)
2021-03-15 18:34:12.958 I Synced 2272825/2317741 (98%, 44916 left)
2021-03-15 18:34:20.494 I Synced 2272845/2317741 (98%, 44896 left)
2021-03-15 18:34:25.765 I Synced 2272865/2317741 (98%, 44876 left)
2021-03-15 18:34:32.745 I Synced 2272885/2317741 (98%, 44856 left)
2021-03-15 18:34:37.663 I Synced 2272905/2317742 (98%, 44837 left)
2021-03-15 18:34:42.128 I Synced 2272925/2317742 (98%, 44817 left)
2021-03-15 18:34:50.988 I Synced 2272945/2317742 (98%, 44797 left)
2021-03-15 18:35:00.758 I Synced 2272965/2317742 (98%, 44777 left)
2021-03-15 18:35:09.981 I Synced 2272985/2317742 (98%, 44757 left)
2021-03-15 18:35:22.230 I Synced 2273005/2317742 (98%, 44737 left)
2021-03-15 18:35:34.544 I Synced 2273025/2317742 (98%, 44717 left, 3% of total synced, estimated 4.4 hours left)
2021-03-15 18:35:46.362 I Synced 2273045/2317742 (98%, 44697 left)
2021-03-15 18:35:55.804 I Synced 2273065/2317742 (98%, 44677 left)
2021-03-15 18:36:05.417 I Synced 2273085/2317742 (98%, 44657 left)
2021-03-15 18:36:18.409 I Synced 2273105/2317742 (98%, 44637 left)
2021-03-15 18:36:27.724 I Synced 2273125/2317742 (98%, 44617 left)
2021-03-15 18:36:36.448 I Synced 2273145/2317742 (98%, 44597 left)
2021-03-15 18:36:48.298 I Synced 2273165/2317742 (98%, 44577 left)
2021-03-15 18:36:57.315 I Synced 2273185/2317742 (98%, 44557 left)
2021-03-15 18:37:08.934 I Synced 2273205/2317742 (98%, 44537 left)
2021-03-15 18:37:17.081 I Synced 2273225/2317742 (98%, 44517 left)
2021-03-15 18:37:24.163 I Synced 2273245/2317742 (98%, 44497 left)
2021-03-15 18:37:33.285 I Synced 2273265/2317742 (98%, 44477 left)
2021-03-15 18:37:44.453 I Synced 2273285/2317742 (98%, 44457 left, 4% of total synced, estimated 4.6 hours left)
2021-03-15 18:37:56.634 I Synced 2273305/2317742 (98%, 44437 left)
2021-03-15 18:38:06.974 I Synced 2273325/2317742 (98%, 44417 left)
2021-03-15 18:38:15.948 I Synced 2273345/2317742 (98%, 44397 left)
2021-03-15 18:38:25.461 I Synced 2273365/2317742 (98%, 44377 left)
2021-03-15 18:38:35.261 I Synced 2273385/2317743 (98%, 44358 left)
2021-03-15 18:38:44.432 I Synced 2273405/2317743 (98%, 44338 left)
2021-03-15 18:38:54.635 I Synced 2273425/2317743 (98%, 44318 left)
2021-03-15 18:39:03.122 I Synced 2273445/2317743 (98%, 44298 left)
2021-03-15 18:39:10.799 I Synced 2273465/2317743 (98%, 44278 left)
2021-03-15 18:39:17.569 I Synced 2273485/2317744 (98%, 44259 left)
2021-03-15 18:39:26.962 I Synced 2273505/2317744 (98%, 44239 left)
2021-03-15 18:39:33.968 I Synced 2273525/2317745 (98%, 44220 left)
2021-03-15 18:39:40.467 I Synced 2273545/2317745 (98%, 44200 left)
2021-03-15 18:39:47.385 I Synced 2273565/2317745 (98%, 44180 left, 4% of total synced, estimated 4.7 hours left)
2021-03-15 18:39:54.330 I Synced 2273585/2317745 (98%, 44160 left)
2021-03-15 18:40:02.064 I Synced 2273605/2317745 (98%, 44140 left)
2021-03-15 18:40:13.743 I Synced 2273625/2317745 (98%, 44120 left)
2021-03-15 18:40:24.367 I Synced 2273645/2317745 (98%, 44100 left)
2021-03-15 18:40:35.647 I Synced 2273665/2317745 (98%, 44080 left)
2021-03-15 18:40:45.504 I Synced 2273685/2317745 (98%, 44060 left)
2021-03-15 18:40:55.232 I Synced 2273705/2317745 (98%, 44040 left)
2021-03-15 18:41:08.255 I Synced 2273725/2317745 (98%, 44020 left)
2021-03-15 18:41:22.578 I Synced 2273745/2317745 (98%, 44000 left)
2021-03-15 18:41:33.067 I Synced 2273765/2317745 (98%, 43980 left)
2021-03-15 18:41:41.165 I Synced 2273785/2317745 (98%, 43960 left)
2021-03-15 18:41:52.421 I Synced 2273805/2317745 (98%, 43940 left, 5% of total synced, estimated 4.8 hours left)
2021-03-15 18:42:02.906 I Synced 2273825/2317745 (98%, 43920 left)
2021-03-15 18:42:12.519 I Synced 2273845/2317745 (98%, 43900 left)
2021-03-15 18:42:19.316 I Synced 2273865/2317745 (98%, 43880 left)
2021-03-15 18:42:27.511 I Synced 2273885/2317745 (98%, 43860 left)
2021-03-15 18:42:36.566 I Synced 2273905/2317745 (98%, 43840 left)
```

So, you can see that it synced 2660 blocks in ~20 minutes.
I have fast SSD ~450 MBs. Network bandwidth: ~25 Mbs.
CPU: Intel Core i5 7300 HQ.
So, why synchronization takes so much time?
Hope for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't seem outrageously slow. It's 133 blocks a minute, or 2 blocks a second.

Monero embeds a set of hashes covering known good hashes, for which it will skip a lot of checking (if you want to disable this and verify everything, use --fast-block-sync 0). These hashes cover maybe 95% of the chain, but of course can't cover the most recent blocks, so these will be fully verified, which is much slower. As new monero versions are released, more and more of the chain is covered by these hashes.